# Why do I get a height and Width of 0?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Why do I get a heigh and Width of 0 with the below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process notePad = new Process();
        notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        notePad.Start();
        IntPtr handle = notePad.Handle;

        RECT windowRect = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        int width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
        int height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;

        Console.WriteLine("Height: " + height + ", Width: " + width);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is my definition of GetWindowRect:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
```

This is my definition for RECT:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
    }
```

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: how did you define RECT?

Comment: I suspect it's a race - try adding a few seconds sleep after the Start() line to let notepad get up and running. Not sure how to wait for this programatically.

Comment: Also, what is the value returned by GetWindowRect?

Comment: @Rup - I just did a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);` after `notepad.Start` and it still gives me 0 for height.

Comment: @Etienne - interesting! I get a false! Why?

Comment: @Kay Straight from MSDN: "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`."

Comment: @Rup: that would be `WaitForInputIdle()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidM thanks - yes, someone's posted that in an answer below too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing a process handle to a function, `GetWindowRect`, that expects a window handle. Naturally, this fails.  You should send `Notepad.MainWindowHandle` instead.

Comment: Damn it! You are right, that works. I thought MainWindowHandle was going to give me the cmd window, but its actually the notePad window that is spawned? THis worked in combo with JSBangs answer.

Comment: @Kay The process handle is something altogether different from a window handle. It's just that in .net, with your P/Invoke, you lose type safety. In plain win32 code you would have got a compiler error when trying to mix process handles and window handles.

Answer (score 5):

You may be querying the size before notepad has fully started up. Try this:

```
    notePad.Start();
    notePad.WaitForInputIdle(); // Waits for notepad to finish startup
    IntPtr handle = notePad.Handle;
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make a difference unfortunately. But it worked in combination with Davids answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like using pinvoke.net to sanity check all my PInvokes.  GetWindowRect is described well at: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowRect.html

Comment: This is what I am actually using and I still can't get it to work. Oh dear, I am a complete noob!

Comment: Are you getting true as the return from GetWindowRect?  If not, you have an error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx